# Strip the last character sent by JavaScript through websockets to Python

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I'm currently trying out websockets, creating a client in JavaScript and a server in Python.

I'm stuck on a simple problem, though: when I send something from the client to the server it always contains a special ending character, but I don't know how to remove it.

I've tried `data[:-1]` thinking that would get rid of it, but it didn't.

With the character my JSON code won't validate.

This is what I send through JavaScript:

```
 ws.send('{"test":"test"}');
```

This is what I get in python:

```
{"test":"test"}�
```

I thought the ending character was \xff

Comment: Can we see some code snippets?

Comment: Can we see your header when posting this through AJAX?

Comment: The WebSocket specification is still very much in flux. Your implementation might be using an older version of the spec, which isn't 100% forward-compatible with the new version. Check to make sure that if you're using a library, you use the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "data[:-1]" is an expression that produces a copy of data missing the last character.  It doesn't modify the "data" variable.  To do that, you have to assign back to "data", like so:

```
data = data[:-1]
```

My suspicion is the "special ending character" is a bug, somewhere, either in your code or how you're using the APIs.  Network code does not generally introduce random characters into the data stream.  Good luck!